# How to make a playlist xspf from a directory with python for VLC?

Tags: python, vlc-media-player, playlists

I need to make with python a program that generate a playlist xspf taking a directory of local music for VLC, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the community. I think you'll find more help if you post your current attempt at solving your need including code examples and detailed description of where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Python program; it looks like it does a lot of what you are asking for.  Possibly a good starting point to adapt to your needs.

https://github.com/chitraanshpopli/create-vlc-playlist/blob/master/create_vlc_playlist.py

Credit to author:  GitHub user chitraanshpopli

====================================
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
import os

ext_list = ['.mp4', '.mkv', '.avi', '.flv', '.mov', '.wmv', '.vob',
'.mpg','.3gp', '.m4v']      #List of extensions to be checked.

check_subdirectories = False        #Set false to get files only from cwd.

class Playlist:
"""Build xml playlist."""

```
def __init__(self):
#Defines basic tree structure.
    self.playlist = xml.Element('playlist')
    self.tree = xml.ElementTree(self.playlist)
    self.playlist.set('xmlns','http://xspf.org/ns/0/')
    self.playlist.set('xmlns:vlc','http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/')
    self.playlist.set('version', '1')

    self.title = xml.Element('title')
    self.playlist.append(self.title)
    self.title.text = 'Playlist'

    self.trackList = xml.Element('trackList')
    self.playlist.append(self.trackList)

def add_track(self, path):
#Add tracks to xml tree (within trackList).
    track = xml.Element('track')
    location = xml.Element('location')
    location.text = path
    track.append(location)
    self.trackList.append(track)

def get_playlist(self):
#Return complete playlist with tracks.
    return self.playlist
```

class Videos:
"""Manage files (videos) to be added to the playlist."""
def **init**(self):
pass

```
def remove_nonvideo_files(self,file_list):
#Removes files whose extension is not mentioned in ext_list from list of files.
    for index,file_name in enumerate(file_list[:]):
        #if file_name.endswith(tuple(ext_list)) or file_name.endswith(tuple(ext_list.upper())) :
        if file_name.endswith(tuple(ext_list)) or file_name.endswith(tuple(ext.upper() for ext in ext_list)):
            pass
        else:
            file_list.remove(file_name)
    return file_list

def edit_paths(self, video_files):
#Add path and prefix to files as required in vlc playlist file. 
    for index in range(len(video_files)):
        video_files[index] =( 
        'file:///' + os.path.join(video_files[index])).replace('\\','/')
    return video_files

def get_videos(self):
#Returns list of video files in the directory.
    if check_subdirectories == True:
        pathlist = [os.getcwd()]    #List of all directories to be scanned.
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
            for name in dirs:
                    subdir_path = os.path.join(root, name)
                    if subdir_path.find('\.') != -1:    #Excludes hidden directoriess.
                        pass
                    else:
                        pathlist.append(subdir_path)
                        
        videos = []
        #Loops through files of root directory and every subdirectory.
        for path in pathlist:
            all_files = os.listdir(path)
            for f in self.remove_nonvideo_files(all_files):
                location = path+ '\\' + f
                videos.append(location)
        return videos
        
    else:
        videos = []
        all_files = os.listdir()
        for f in self.remove_nonvideo_files(all_files):
                location = os.getcwd() + '\\' + f
                videos.append(location)
        return videos
```

def main():

```
playlist = Playlist()
videos = Videos()

video_files = videos.get_videos()
video_paths = videos.edit_paths(video_files)

for path in video_paths:
    playlist.add_track(path)

playlist_xml = playlist.get_playlist()
with open('songs.xspf','w') as mf:
    mf.write(xml.tostring(playlist_xml).decode('utf-8'))
```

main()

'''
playlist(ROOT)
title /title
trackList
track
location file:///path /location
title                 /title
image                 /image
duration              /duration
/track
/tracklist
/playlist
'''